# (Android java, JSON) Why it lose the stored values?

Tags: java, android

I have a JSONParser named class that finds all needed informations I need. I make an ArrayList variable and fill the data as it has to do. But... if I try to get this ArrayList from other activity, it does not give back any value...

```
public class JSONParser {
    ArrayList<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();

public JSONParser() {
    new getAllURLs().execute("https://...");
}

public ArrayList<Day> getDays() {
        return days;
}

public void writeout() {
        for (Day i : days) Log.e("Writeout", i.getDate());
    }
}
```

For example if I call the writeout() function from a function that's also in this JSONParser class, it works perfectly, I get all the dates in Logcat as I have to. But if I try this in the main activity:

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    jsonParser.writeout();
```

It does not do anything... Does not write anything in Logcat. If I type this

```
jsonParser.writeout();
```

In main activity, and a simple

```
writeout();
```

in the activity where I parsed the json files and I run the app when both is in the code, I get the dates only once...

Maybe anyone knows why is this?

Answer (score 0):

So whenever you call `JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();` you are creating a whole new object with its own arraylist (which may not have your URLs in it).  What you want is a single object that all your classes can share.  A simple and common way to do this is by using the singleton pattern.

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/core-java-simply-singleton.html

```java
public class JSONParser {
    private static JSONParser instance;

    private ArrayList<Day> days = new ArrayList<>();

    public static JSONParser getInstance(){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new JSONParser();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private JSONParser() {
        new getAllURLs().execute("https://...");
    }

    public ArrayList<Day> getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void writeout() {
        for (Day i : days) Log.e("Writeout", i.getDate());
    }
}
```

Now you'll call `JSONParser.getInstance();` each time you need to use it instead of `new JSONParser()` and you'll get a single instance of the class.

Make sure to be careful that you're not trying to have multiple classes make writes on the arraylist at the same time!  Or one writes while the other reads.  This can lead to race conditions.

Comment: All I want to call the new JSONParse();, let the JSONParse class work, build up a list and then make it possible to have this list in another activities... Normally the "jsonParser" should have the data I built up since it is a simple object... And I want an object's value... I have to call this "new JSONParse()" only once, to make the constructor run and get the data from json files.

Comment: In that execute() command I have an URL that leads to a json files what stores the urls of json files. Everything works perfectly, the only problem it forgets what data it has and says it is empty ...

Comment: Do you close the handler to read the file after you are done reading it in the instance of the class that works?  It's possible that your second class cannot read the file because the first one already has it open.  Put in some breakpoints and make sure both instances of the class actually populate the arraylist.  The arraylist shouldn't just go blank.  It's more likely that it just isn't being filled in the second time.

Comment: My code works like this: I open the first URL where is only one JSONArray where it can find an ID and an URL to the actual JSON file that has the data I need -> for (int i = 0; i < URLS.length(); i++) JSONObject url = URLS.getJSONObject(); String urlString = url.getString("url"); new getObjectFromOneURL().execute(url);

Comment: I made a variable: ArrayList<String> allURL = new ArrayList<>(); - where I want to store the URLs I get from the first JSON file, but even those Strings cannot be reached from the first activity, while the "allURL" variable stores the right information after I read it and stored it...

Comment: Yeah, can you post the code you use to open and read from the file?  Are both instances of the class correctly opening and reading from the file?